# Using External Bluetooth dongle in ICS 4.0.3 Tablet

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, bluetooth, tablet

I have a HCL Me U1 Tablet with Android ICS 4.0.3 OS. [Specification](http://www.hclstore.in/Products/HCL-Handheld-Devices-ME-Tablets/HCL-ME/HCL-ME-Tablet-U1/pid-505298.aspx)

It does not have internal bluetooth but has a Micro-USB and USB port.

I would like to know if bluetooth devices can be accessed by connecting an external bluetooth dongle through the USB port. 
And are there any apps for the same?

I have not rooted my tablet yet.

Any guidance on how to achieve it?

Comment: State what kernel version is it? Settings > About > Kernel version will tell you what it is :)]

Comment: @t0mm13b : The kernel version is 3.0.8